# RegEx: how to match specific numbers in the body of an <a href> tag

Tags: regex

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/.../">5 (15%)</a>
```

I want a RegEx that would match the number before the parentheses: i.e `5`
and another RegEX that would match the number inside the parentheses (together with the % symbol) i.e. `15%`

Thank you

Comment: So what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Similar to `/\([0-9]/)/`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide any of my initial efforts in my question, but they were all so simple (see my comment above), that I thought that they wouldn't contribute to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'<a [^>]*>[^(]*[(]([^)]+)'
```

That is: the first thing enclosed in parentheses in the body of an `a` tag.

Comment: Scott, thanks a lot. I would never manage to write this myself!
And, using this site http://regex101.com/ and based on your RegEx I managed to tweak it to: `<a [^>]*>([0-9]*)[^(]` which matches the number before the parentheses, i.e 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser instead of a regex for hell a lot of reasons.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.someurl.com/.../">5 (15%)</a>';
console.log(el.childNodes[0].text.replace(/^[^(]+/, "")); // (15%)
```

Comment: You think that because he mentioned HTML but his problem has nothing to do with HTML.